# What happens when I open/close a file?

Tags: kernel, system-calls

Kernels provide hardware abstraction with **system calls**, such as `read()` and `write()`. Many of them are fairly intuitive, but I really don't understand what `open()` and `close()` are.

Wikipedia says that

> `open` and `close` respectively initialize and terminate access to a file.

What actually happens, at the hardware level, when I open/close a file?

Comment: I would imagine memory gets allocated/deallocated among other things.

Comment: Given that the OS doesn't know where on the physical hard disk a given file is located (that's handled by the drive control software on the drive itself, or so I've been told) this method likely makes a request to the drive controller to locate the file, allocate memory, and possibly some other OS related tasks.  Close would do the opposite: free the memory and release the drive controller.  But I do not know for sure.

Comment: Linux or Windows? Even if there are quite a lot of similar things and concepts, both OSes remain fairly different.

Comment: @OznOg I am more interested in Linux

Comment: open and close don't act on hardware level. They administer handles.

Comment: In Linux everything is accessed via descriptors, including `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. `open()` asks kernel to allocate a descriptor for I/O and `close()` de-allocates it. A descriptor is a buffer used by kernel to copy data to and from the target device. It might interest you to read on "writing kernel modules and drivers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unix like systems, the idea is to manipulate resources throught files (mainly entries in the file system, and access with read/write/open/close/ioctl for the most common ones).

The open() and close() can thus be seen as ways to take/release a handle on a specific resource.

In many situations, the open/close calls just perform allocations of resources at a software level (just allocate memory or register in some framework, or take a lock, etc...), but obviously it sometime generates hardware accesses.

The implementation lying under the open()/close() calls is always driver dependent and the programmer may put really specific thing in it.

You may find so overview of those implementations in https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ or http://idak.gop.edu.tr/esmeray/UnderStandingKernel.pdf or even reading the kernel sources http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/mousedev.c?v=3.10#L530 (example for a mouse device)

You'll even figure out that what you consider as 'fairly intuitive' is actually not. Even a simple read() can become fairly complicated in case you perform IOs on a software RAID disk, for example.